# RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID] when checking for permission overwrites (Discord.js v12)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I was trying to create a lock command where the user can select what permission gets overwritten. However, this only works if the 3rd and 4th `if` statements (which check for existing permission overwrites) are removed as the following error is produced: `RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number.` Would there be a workaround for this?

```
const channel = bot.channels.cache.get(args[0]);

      if(!channel) {
        return message.reply('Please provide a channel id!');
      }

      if(!args[1]) {
        return message.reply('Please set the lock type!');
      }

      if (!channel.permissionsFor(message.guild.roles.everyone).has('VIEW_CHANNEL')) {
        const errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(`❌ \`VIEW_CHANNEL\` for \`${channel.name}\` is already disabled.`)
          .setColor('RED');
        return message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
      }

      if (!channel.permissionsFor(message.guild.roles.everyone).has('READ_MESSAGES')) {
        const errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
          .setDescription(`❌ \`READ_MESSAGES\` for \`${channel.name}\` is already disabled.`)
          .setColor('RED');
        return message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
      }

      else if (args[1] === 'view' || args[1] === 'read') {
        channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { VIEW_CHANNEL: false }).then(() => {
          const msgEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`✅ The channel\`${message.channel.name}\` has been locked.`)
            .setColor('GREEN');
          message.channel.send(msgEmbed);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          const errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`❌ Unable to lock \`${channel.name}\`.`)
            .setColor('RED');
          message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
        });
      }
      else if (args[1] === 'send') {
        channel.updateOverwrite(message.channel.guild.roles.everyone, { SEND_MESSAGES: false }).then(() => {
          const msgEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`✅ The channel\`${channel.name}\` has been locked.`)
            .setColor('GREEN');
          message.channel.send(msgEmbed);
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          const errorEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setDescription(`❌ Unable to lock \`${channel.name}\`.`)
            .setColor('RED');
          message.channel.send(errorEmbed);
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's because you're using `READ_MESSAGES` instead of using `VIEW_CHANNEL` everywhere (it's the same and I think `READ_MESSAGES` has been removed from Discord.js v12).

Comment: Thanks, yes I had actually used `READ_MESSAGES` instead of `SEND_MESSAGES`